# Query Optimization in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose

I have two collections. In one collection i have stored search strings while in other actual data exists. I need to find the records from Data Collection based on Search strings stored in Search Collection.

(1) Search Collection:

```
     [{_id:123, search: paris}, 

    {_id:123, search: london}, 

    {_id:123, search: tokyo}]
```

(2) Data Collection:

```
     [{_id:123, content: Paris is capital of France}, 

    {_id:123, content: Have you ever went to London?}, 

    {_id:123, content: Where is Tokyo?}, 

{_id:123, content: I heard about Singapore as well}]
```

Issue is i have more than 50 search strings and in data collection i have millions of records. My current implementation is as follows:

```
 const src = await SearchCollection.find();


  for (let i = 0; i (is less than) src.length; i++) { 

    let msg = await DataCollection.find({ 


          content: { 

            $regex: new RegExp(src[i].search)), 

            $options: "gi" 

          } 


    });
```

Obviously this query is very slow. If there are 50 search strings, it will loop through 50 times and also the data contents are in millions. How to deal with my current scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Create a text index on `content` field and use text search.

```
db.text.insertMany([
  { "_id" : 1, "content" : "Paris is capital of France" },
  { "_id" : 2, "content" : "Have you ever went to London?" },
  { "_id" : 3, "content" : "Where is Tokyo?" },
  { "_id" : 4, "content" : "I heard about Singapore as well" }
])
db.text.createIndex({content:"text"})
db.text.find({$text:{$search:"London"}})
```

That would be way faster than regex, since it would use the index.

References:

- [Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)
- [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text)

Comment: That's fine. My issue is i have search strings in another array. So i don't want to loop  and run query 50 times. Like in your solution i not only want to search with "London", in fact i want to search with all strings present in collection.

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you are looping 50 times through millions of records without an index. try this then: `db.text.find({$text:{$search:"paris london tokyo"}}) `- seems like that's what you need.